# Avalonia UI C# XAML WPF - Adjust data grid row color based on column value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, avalonia

```
public class EventLogView : UserControl
{
    private DataGrid dataGrid;
    public EventLogView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        dataGrid = this.FindControl<DataGrid>("EventLogsDataGrid");
        this.dataGrid.LoadingRow += new EventHandler<DataGridRowEventArgs>(dataGrid_LoadingRows);
    } 

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(this);
    }

    void dataGrid_LoadingRows(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

I would like to change every row color to the red, if the 4th column's value is "HIGH".

Comment: https://pastebin.com/bQMcYG9f

Comment: In the code-behind I have access to this specific DataGrid object, I can change each row to be red-colored, but I do not have access to the columns' values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this in "pure" WPF would be to define an `ItemContainerStyle` with a `DataTrigger`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="EventLogsDataGrid"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  Items="{Binding LogsData}"
                  CanUserReorderColumns="True"
                  CanUserResizeColumns="True"
                  IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Importance}" Value="HIGH">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}"
                                Header="ID"
                                Width="Auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Content}"
                                Header="Content"
                                Width="Auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CreationDate}"
                                Header="Date Time"
                                Width="Auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Source}"
                                Header="Source"
                                Width="Auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Importance}"
                                Header="Priority"
                                Width="Auto"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

But since Avalonia doesn't support triggers, you may have to handle the `LoadingRow` event something like this to set the `Background` property programmtically:

```
void dataGrid_LoadingRows(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    var dataObject = e.Row.DataContext as YourDataObject;
    if (dataObject != null && dataObject.Importance == "HIGH")
        e.Row.Background = Brushes.Red;
}
```

Comment: That gives me: Unable to resolve type DataTrigger from namespace https://github.com/avaloniaui

Comment: @Matheew: Replace the `DataTrigger` with a `DataTriggerBehavior` as shown [here](https://gist.github.com/darinkes/5c3b4317099e060a7d7c9c4e0bc68682) then.

Comment: I don't know why, but it also doesn't work, it generates the same error, I've read the article you had linked above.

Comment: A huge thank you for helping me solve this problem! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

There may be another way to do the same thing, but in XAML. To be honest, I don’t compete the quest, but it was really close. The author of Avalonia.Xaml.Behaviors Wiesław Šoltés has posted an example of [a very interesting approach](https://github.com/wieslawsoltes/AvaloniaBehaviors/blob/f235559d91acb9a2b051ef40a4ae1bb9a0752446/samples/DragAndDropSample/Views/MainWindow.axaml#L84-L90). I tried to adopt it for use with the DataGrid’s row and it almost worked:

```cs
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:int="clr-namespace:Avalonia.Xaml.Interactivity;assembly=Avalonia.Xaml.Interactivity"
        xmlns:ia="clr-namespace:Avalonia.Xaml.Interactions.Core;assembly=Avalonia.Xaml.Interactions"        
        x:Class="BvsDesktopLinux.Views.MainWindow" ...>
...
<Window.Styles>
    <Style Selector="DataGridCell.statusColumn">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24"/>
        <Setter Property="(int:Interaction.Behaviors)">
            <int:BehaviorCollectionTemplate>
                <int:BehaviorCollection>
                    <ia:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding Status}" ComparisonCondition="Equal" Value="Rejected">
                        <ia:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="DataGridCell" PropertyName="Background" Value="Red" />
                    </ia:DataTriggerBehavior>
                </int:BehaviorCollection>
            </int:BehaviorCollectionTemplate>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Styles>
...
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="10"
          Items="{Binding Banknotes}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBanknote}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.NoteId}" Binding="{Binding Id}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.NoteCurrency}" Binding="{Binding Currency}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.NoteDenomination}" Binding="{Binding Denomination}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Status}" Binding="{Binding Status}" CellStyleClasses="statusColumn" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I only had one problem with the code – the binding doesn't use the DataGridCell's DataContext (the element of the ObservableCollection from the ViewModel), but it uses the DataContext of the whole View/Window (ViewModel).

Answer (score 0):

@mm8: Thanks for the useful hint! I was looking for the same answer and started with your advice. I ran into a problem after sorting the rows, or reloading the content with some modifications. Several rows that didn't match the criteria had the background property attached. So I used styles to attach/detach the style:

```cs
<Window.Styles>
    <Style Selector="DataGridRow.rejectedStatus">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Styles>
```

```cs
private void DataGrid_OnLoadingRow(object? sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    var dataObject = e.Row.DataContext as Models.Banknote;
    if (dataObject != null && dataObject.Status == "Rejected")
    {
        e.Row.Classes.Add("rejectedStatus");
    }
    else
    {
        e.Row.Classes.Remove("rejectedStatus");
    }
}
```